# Complex format specifier C

Tags: c, format, specifier

Can someone explain me what king of specifier is in the below code? and give me an example.

`printf("\r\x1b[32mConverting: \x1b[36m%d\x1b[0m",(Convert));`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These ascii special codes are used to color debug messages.
    \x1b[32m gives green color to "convering"
    \x1b[36m%d gives cyan color to the Convert integer
and     \x1b[0m%d finally resets the color values.
    \r is carriage return

%d is nothing but the format specifier for integers
https://www.quora.com/What-does-d-mean-in-the-C-programming-language

Comment: Explain initial `\r` and your answer will be complete.

Answer (score 1):

The string contains two [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). To find out what they mean `\x1b[` is denoted by `CSI` in the linked article, e.g. `\x1b[32m` corresponds to what wikipedia denotes by `CSI n m`:

```
CSI n m
SGR – Select Graphic Rendition
Sets SGR parameters, including text color. After CSI can be zero or more parameters separated with ;. With no parameters, CSI m is treated as CSI 0 m (reset / normal), which is typical of most of the ANSI escape sequences.
```

Comment: What \x1b and 36m%d are?